# Wordpress not recognizing SQL database

Tags: sql, wordpress

I used a third party for hosting and before I knew what I was doing, I created an entire WordPress website (via the host's WP panel) before getting my domain name. I now have my domain and I’m trying to get all the pages/etc transferred over to that domain’s WP. But the new WP Admin panel is not showing any of the old content.

What I’ve done so far:
Uploaded all the files (wp_admin, wp_content, wp_includes) to the new domain folder

Updated the wp_config file to reflect the new address

Exported the original SQL file and went through and changed all instances of my old domain to my new one

Uploaded the new SQL file via FTP

I don’t know what else to do :( no matter what, I can never get the files/pages/ anything to show on the new WP admin panel.

Comment: Did you import the updated SQL to the correct database?

Comment: Yes I did. And I wrote I uploaded via ftp but that was wrong. I used my phpmyadmin to do it. I verified that the new sql showing for my new database is in fact the one I want. But nothing is reflecting on the wordpress admin

Comment: Also, I just noticed that my themes and plugins migrated over but nothing else??

Comment: Since you get to the admin dashboard, if you change the site title or tag line (blogname or blogdescription) do you see the updated values in the `options` table of the desired database?

Comment: Yes, I just changed it to test it and it was reflected in the desired database. It appears that media files, pages and certain plugin files are not being 'seen' for some reason.

Comment: Did you update permalinks (just change save and change back and save)?

Comment: Yes, I've updated permalinks as well. I've scoured the net for hours, trying every 'solution' I can find and none of them work :(     Edit: I just tried creating a new page with the same name as one in my database and Wordpress automatically named it page-2, so it SEES it but it's not loading it in the admin panel

Comment: Did you double check your steps from the codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress?

Comment: Yes :( I did that as well. I can only guess that something in the wp_post and wp_upload sections of the sql is messed up but for the life of me I don't know.

Comment: try upload every file in your old wp root folder,export the old wp db using phpmyadmin.  then create a new database in your new server and import it. update wp-config file and tryu again

Comment: No go. I give up :( I'm just gonna have to redo the entire site.